# How to mention a bot in ms teams, using BOT SDK framework

Tags: bots, microsoft-teams, microsoft-graph-teams, teams-toolkit

This is not possible using Webhooks([Reference](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/teams-developer/incoming-webhook-to-mention-a-bot/m-p/4040243)), is it possible for a bot to mention another bot?